# Error while conversion spreadsheetml to xlsx

Tags: xml, xlsx, spreadsheetml

i am generating a SpreadsheetML but now i need to it with xlsx extension . is there any unix utility to convert SpreadsheetML to xlsx  ?

i have tried changing the extension directly but pivot tables are getting lost .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a workbook in excel, extract the zip contents, manually replace the worksheet xml file (`/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`) with the one you want, and re-zip.